# Generate All scripts with Create and Alter statements for Table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to generate all scripts in my database. As you know, clicking "Generate Scripts", it outputs all tables, all stored procedures etc. with `CREATE` statements.

How can I get an `ALTER` statement for recently changed tables and `CREATE` statement for recently added tables, at the same time?

As an example, A, B, C, D tables were created before. Then I add a new table as E and I changed a column name in C. When I click "Generate Scripts", it must output:

```
IF NOT EXISTS ....
CREATE TABLE A
....

IF NOT EXISTS ....
CREATE TABLE B
....

IF NOT EXISTS ....
CREATE TABLE C
....

IF NOT EXISTS ....
CREATE TABLE D
....

IF NOT EXISTS ....
CREATE TABLE E
....

ALTER TABLE C
MODIFY COLUMN XX...
```

like this.

[image: Generate scripts]

Comment: not possible from SSMS

Comment: Is it impossible with manuel? I try that : I opened generated script file, replaced CREATE TABLE with ALTER TABLE. But in this situation, I lost CREATE statement of my new table. etc.

Comment: You may try using Microsoft Visual Studio Database Projects; It generates dacpac files that serve your purpose

Comment: Thanks a lot. I can try.

Comment: Take a look at this related thread with an excellent reply from Aaron Bertrand http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/53085/is-there-a-way-to-generate-table-create-script-in-tsql

Answer (score 0):

Generate Scripts will just give you the create statements for the various objects in your database. It sounds like you're looking for a source control system, which would be able to generate CREATE/ALTER statements depending on changes from what is in source control.

Comment: Is there a source control system for this situation?

Comment: I think any/all are probably able to generate deployment scripts based on the differences between what's in source control and what's live. I'm in an environment where TFS is used, and I use Redgate SQL Source Control with it.

Answer (score 0):

Use SSMS to generate your scripts into a new query window, then in SSMS in that new query window do a find and replace using a RegEx search.

So if your script contains Functions click ***Ctrl+H*** then:

Search item:  (create.*function)

Replacement item: create or alter function

Then replace as needed